# Why did Mr. Jack not stop the stranger?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

Mr. Jack was lying in his own house. A stranger entered the house.The stranger saw Mr. Jack, Mr. Jack also saw the stranger. The stranger took away all the expensive things from the house and went away. Mr. Jack did not stop him or shout at him though he was 100% healthy and normal. He did not even call the police. Why?

(There will be no imaginable answers, such as: dream)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think he didn't stop him because

> The stranger was from a moving company. Mr. Jack is moving to a new house!

Alternatively, it could be a

> debt collector.

Comment: If he is from a moving company hired by mr Jack, how is he a stranger?

Comment: @Jasen Do you commonly find yourself sufficiently acquainted with random employees of companies you infrequently have personal interactions with to no longer consider them strangers?  Bank tellers, cab drivers, flight attendants?  Just because you hired a service company doesn't mean you're going to know the person who actually renders that service on your behalf; it's far more likely they'll be a stranger, unless you're a frequent customer and/or the available pool of people who might render the service is very small indeed.

Comment: After an introduction someone is an acuaitance, not a stranger.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer this explanation:

> Mr Jack is a Cat.

Answer (score -1):

> Mr. Jack was disarmed, stranger -- with weapon. Stranger thought Mr.Jack was sleeping.

Comment: Your scenario would almost certainly end with the police being called, where the puzzle calls for a scenario where that wouldn't happen.